# How to filter and log null objects in Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to wrap my head around java8 streams and was wondering if someone can help me with it.

In old java,

```
List<Obj> newObjs = ArrayList<Obj>();
for (Obj obj : objects){
  if(obj == null){
     logger.error("null object");
  }
  else{
    newObjs.add(...)
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to filter null objects and also log it.
What's a good way to do this in java 8?

Comment: Yeah. I see that we can filter(Object::nonNull) but are you suggesting that to log things would be to filter(Object::isNull). can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Can you use a method? So `stream.filter(this::nonNullLogged)`, and then `void nonNullLogged() { if (obj != null) { return true } else { logger.error("blah"); return false }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) and put an if statement inside it:

```
List<Obj> newObjs = objects.stream().peek(x -> {
    if (x == null) logger.error("null object");
}).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this kind of loses the conciseness of the streams, so personally I would still use a plain old for loop for something simple like "filtering nulls and collecting to a list".

Keep in mind that Streams *do not* replace for loops. Don't use streams just because it's new and shiny.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to move that logic into different method

```
public boolean filter(Object obj) {

  if(obj == null){
      logger.error("null object");
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

And then just stream the list

```
objects.stream().filter(this::filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
```